# How to display text from ArrayList in a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jtextarea

I am using swing right now to create a homerun derby mini game in java swing. This is my first time using swing and I am having trouble using my ArrayList that contains player data. I am trying to display the data within the ArrayList into a JTextArea, but can't seem to figure it out.

UI Class:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class UI extends JPanel {

DerbyManager dm;

JFrame window;
public JPanel bgPanel[] = new JPanel[50];
public JTextArea info = new JTextArea();
public JLabel bgLabel[] = new JLabel[50];
public ImageIcon bgIcon[] = new ImageIcon[50];

public UI(DerbyManager dm) {

    this.dm = dm;
    

    createMainField();
    generateScene();


    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void createMainField() {

    window = new JFrame("Ichiro's Secret Slugfest");
    window.setSize(800, 600);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    window.setLayout(null);
    
}

public void createBackground(int bgNum, String bgFileName) {

    bgPanel[bgNum] = new JPanel();
    bgPanel[bgNum].setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
    bgPanel[bgNum].setBackground(null);
    bgPanel[bgNum].setLayout(null);
    window.add(bgPanel[bgNum]);

    bgLabel[bgNum] = new JLabel();
    bgLabel[bgNum].setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);

    ImageIcon bgIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(bgFileName));
    bgLabel[bgNum].setIcon(bgIcon);

}

public ArrayList<Player> createInfo(int bgNum, int x, int y, int width, int height, String name) {
    
    ArrayList<Player> derby = new ArrayList<Player>();

    JTextArea info = new JTextArea();
    info.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    
    for(Player d : derby) {
        if(name == d.getName()) {
            info.append(d.getName());
        }
        else {
            info.append("Player Not Found");
        }
    }
    
    derby.add(new Player(0, "Ichiro Suzuki", "OF", "Seattle Mariners", 84, "C", "A", 60.0, 3089, .311, 117, .757,
            "Ichiro is one of TWO players to have won the ROTY and the MVP award in the same season."));
    
    derby.add(new Player(1, "Ty Cobb", "CF", "Detroit Tigers", 78, "D", "A", 151.5, 4189, .366, 117, .944,
            "'The Georgia Peach' wasn't considered a power hitter, but said to be able to hit a home run on comand."));
    
    derby.add(new Player(2, "Lou Brock", "LF", "St. Louis Cardinals", 82, "C", "A", 45.3, 3023, .293, 149, .753,
            "'The Georgia Peach' wasn't considered a power hitter, but said to be able to hit a home run on comand."));
    
    derby.add(new Player(3, "Jackie Robinson", "LF, IF", "Brooklyn Dodgers", 86, "C", "A", 45.3, 3023, .293, 149, .753,
            "'The Georgia Peach' wasn't considered a power hitter, but said to be able to hit a home run on comand."));

    derby.add(new Player(4, "Barry Bonds", "LF", "San Francisco Giants", 99, "A", "A", 162.8, 2935, .298, 762, 1.051,
            "Barry Bonds is considered to be the most feared hitter of all-time, tallying 688 intention walks in his career."));
    
    derby.add(new Player(5, "Bo Jackson", "CF", "Kansas City Royals", 91, "A", "C", 183.1, 2873, .342, 714, 1.164,
            "'The Sultan of Swat', 'The Titan of Terror', 'The Clolussus of Clout', 'The King of Crash'... 'The Great Bambino'!"));
    
    derby.add(new Player(6, "Ted Williams", "LF", "Boston Red Sox", 97, "A", "A", 122.0, 2654, .344, 521, 1.116,
            "A coin flip or is Ted Williams getting on base? Teddy Ballgame recorded a career OBP of .482!"));
    
    derby.add(new Player(7, "Babe Ruth", "OF, P", "New York Yankees", 99, "A", "A", 183.1, 2873, .342, 714, 1.164,
            "'The Sultan of Swat', 'The Titan of Terror', 'The Clolussus of Clout', 'The King of Crash'... 'The Great Bambino'!"));
    
    return derby;
    }


public void createButton(int bgNum, int x, int y, int width, int height, String buttonFileName, String action) {
    ImageIcon buttonIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(buttonFileName));

    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    button.setBackground(null);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setIcon(buttonIcon);
    button.addActionListener(dm.aHandler);
    button.setActionCommand(action);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    

    bgPanel[bgNum].add(button);
}

public void createObject(int bgNum, int objX, int objY, int objWidth, int objHeight, String objFileName) {

    //CREATE OBJECTS
    JLabel objectLabel = new JLabel();
    //      objectLabel.setBounds(25, 25, 332, 236);
    objectLabel.setBounds(objX, objY, objWidth, objHeight);

    ImageIcon objectIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(objFileName));
    objectLabel.setIcon(objectIcon);

    bgPanel[bgNum].add(objectLabel);

}

public void createCard(int bgNum, int x, int y, int width, int height, String cardFileName, String action) {
    ImageIcon cardIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(cardFileName));

    JButton card = new JButton();
    card.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    card.setBackground(null);
    card.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    card.setFocusPainted(false);
    card.setIcon(cardIcon);
    card.addActionListener(dm.aHandler);
    card.setActionCommand(action);
    card.setBorderPainted(true);
    

    bgPanel[bgNum].add(card);
}

public void generateScene() {

    //MAIN MENU
    createBackground(1, "Ichiro Gif.gif");
        //BUTTONS
        createButton(1, 282, 508, 236, 59, "Play Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //CONTAINER
        createObject(1, 0, 480, 400, 120, "Player Container.png");
        createObject(1, 400, 480, 400, 120, "Player Container.png");
    
    bgPanel[1].add(bgLabel[1]);

    //PLAYER INTRODUCTIONS
    createBackground(2, "Menu Background.png");
        //PLAYERS
        createCard(2, 25, 91, 130, 183, "Ichiro Flopps Menu.png", "ichiroCard");
        createCard(2, 180, 91, 130, 183, "Jimmie Fox Flopps Menu.png", "jimmieCard");
        createCard(2, 335, 91, 130, 183, "Barry Bonds Flopps Menu.png", "barryCard");
        createCard(2, 490, 91, 130, 183, "Ted Williams Flopps Menu.png", "tedCard");
        createCard(2, 25, 296, 130, 183, "Babe Ruth Flopps Menu.png", "babeCard");
        createCard(2, 180, 296, 130, 183, "Bo Jackson Flopps Menu.png", "boCard");
        createCard(2, 335, 296, 130, 183, "Rogers Hornsby Flopps Menu.png", "rogersCard");
        createCard(2, 490, 296, 130, 183, "Ty Cobb Flopps Menu.png", "tyCard");
        //BUTTONS
        createButton(2, 582, 525, 200, 50, "Play Button.png", "derby");
        createButton(2, 25, 525, 200, 50, "Exit Button.png", "mainMenu");
        //CARD CONTAINERS
        createObject(2, 645, 91, 130, 183, "Player Container.png");
        createObject(2, 645, 296, 130, 183, "Player Container.png");
        //MENU CONTAINER
        createObject(2, 0, 505, 400, 95, "Player Container.png");
        createObject(2, 400, 505, 400, 95, "Player Container.png");
        bgPanel[2].add(bgLabel[2]);
    
    //ICHIRO
        createBackground(3, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(3, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Ichiro Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(3, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        createInfo(3,  286, 25, 489, 332, "Ichiro Suzuki");
        //DYK?
        createObject(3, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(3, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(3, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[3].add(bgLabel[3]);
        
    //JIMMIE FOX
        createBackground(4, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(4, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Jimmie Fox Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(4, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(4, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(4, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(4, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[4].add(bgLabel[4]);
        
    //BARRY BONDS
        createBackground(5, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(5, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Barry Bonds Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(5, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(5, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(5, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(5, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[5].add(bgLabel[5]);
        
    //TED WILLIAMS
        createBackground(6, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(6, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Ted Williams Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(6, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(6, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(6, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(6, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[6].add(bgLabel[6]);
    
    //BABE RUTH
        createBackground(7, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(7, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Babe Ruth Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(7, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(7, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(7, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(7, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[7].add(bgLabel[7]);
        
    //BO JACKSON
        createBackground(8, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(8, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Bo Jackson Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(8, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(8, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(8, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(8, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[8].add(bgLabel[8]);
        
    //ROGERS HORNSBY
        createBackground(9, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(9, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Rogers Hornsby Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(9, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(9, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(9, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(9, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[9].add(bgLabel[9]);
        
    //TY COBB
        createBackground(10, "Menu Background.png");
        //CARD
        createObject(10, 25, 25, 236, 332, "Ty Cobb Flopps.png");
        //STATS
        createObject(10, 286, 25, 489, 332, "Player Container.png");
        //DYK?
        createObject(10, 286, 382, 489, 193, "Player Container.png");
        //BACK BUTTON
        createButton(10, 25, 382, 236, 59, "Back Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        //PICK BUTTON
        createButton(10, 25, 466, 236, 59, "Pick Button 236px.png", "playerSelect");
        
        bgPanel[10].add(bgLabel[10]);
        
    //DERBY
        createBackground(11, "Derby Background.png");
        //EXIT BUTTON
        bgPanel[11].add(bgLabel[11]);
}
}
```

Player Class:

```
package Main;

public final class Player {
//Player info
private int number;
private String name;
private String position;
private String team;
//Player ratings
private int OVR;
private String power;
private String contact;
//Player career statistics
private double WAR;
private int H;
private double BA;
private int HR;
private double OPS;
//Player fun fact
private String fact;

public Player(int number, String name, String position, String team, int OVR, String power, String contact,
    double WAR, int H, double BA, int HR, double OPS, String fact) {
    
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position;
    this.team = team;
    this.OVR = OVR;
    this.power = power;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.WAR = WAR;
    this.H = H;
    this.BA = BA;
    this.HR = HR;
    this.OPS = OPS;
    this.fact = fact;
}

//getters
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public String getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public int getOVR() {
    return OVR;
}

public String getPower() {
    return power;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public double getWAR() {
    return WAR;
}

public int getH() {
    return H;
}

public double getBA() {
    return BA;
}

public int getHR() {
    return HR;
}

public double getOPS() {
    return OPS;
}

public String getFact() {
    return fact;
}

//setters
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public void setTeam(String team) {
    this.team = team;
}

public void setOVR(int OVR) {
    this.OVR = OVR;
}

public void setPower(String power) {
    this.power = power;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public void setWAR(double WAR) {
    this.WAR = WAR;
}

public void setH(int H) {
    this.H = H;
}

public void setBA(double BA) {
    this.BA = BA;
}

public void setHR(int HR) {
    this.HR = HR;
}

public void setOPS(double OPS) {
    this.OPS = OPS;
}

public void setFact(String fact) {
    this.fact = fact;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("\n%d OVR | %d %s | %s | %s\nContact: %s | Power: %s\nCareer Stats: %.1f WAR | %d H | %.3f BA | %d HR | %.3f OPS" + "\n%s"
            , OVR, name, number, position, team, contact, power, WAR, H, BA, HR, OPS, fact);
}
}
```

DerbyManager:

```
package Main;

import java.net.URL;

import Event.Event01;

public class DerbyManager {

ActionHandler aHandler = new ActionHandler(this);
public UI ui = new UI(this);
public SceneChanger sChanger = new SceneChanger(this);
Music music = new Music();
SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect();
public Event01 ev1 = new Event01(this);

//GAME SOUND
public URL sweetTea = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Music/Sweet Tea.wav");
public URL jamesFranco = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Music/James Franco.wav");
public URL snowblood = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Music/Snowblood.wav");
public URL powerPros = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Music/Power Pros.wav");
public URL play = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Sound Effect/Play Button.wav");

public URL currentMusic;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new DerbyManager();

    
}

public DerbyManager() {
    
    currentMusic = jamesFranco;
    playMusic(currentMusic);
    sChanger.mainMenu();
}

public void playMusic(URL url) {
    music.setFile(url);
    music.play(url);
    music.loop(url);
}

public void stopMusic(URL url) {
    music.stop(url);
}

public void playSound(URL url) {
    sound.play(url);
}
}
```

I want to be able to display the stats and information of the player when click on their card in JTextArea. Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: What is **DerbyManager**?

Comment: I added the DerbyManager class now @DevilsHnd

Comment: *"I added the DerbyManager class now"* Given 'sounds' have nothing to do with the problem, it would've been better to make an MRE as suggested in the first comment, that in no way depends on loading sounds irrelevant to the problem & only available on your machine. Don't forget, you're the only person here who actually cares if the problem is sovled. For everyone else, it is purely academic.

Answer (score 0):

Although the provided code is not runnable (because a lot is missing), there are some (well, several) things I would do somewhat differently. This is not to say you should do this, but it may provide you with some ideas to think about.

I would most likely make the `ArrayList<Player> derby = new ArrayList<Player>();` a public static member variable using a List Interface instead of an ArrayList, for example:

```
public class UI extends JPanel {

    public static List<Player> derby = new ArrayList<>();

    // .....  The rest of class code  .....
```

I would most likely fill this List from either a database table or a CSV style text file rather than hard-coded data as done within the `UI.createInfo()` method.

Doing this would allow this data within the List to be potentially used anywhere within the application. Currently, the `UI.createInfo()` method returns an `ArrayList<Player>` yet, this returned value is not utilized anywhere. Instead, the `UI.createInfo()` accepts arguments that permit it to display information about a specific player if that player is found within the ArrayList. This is the probable cause to you entire situation but more on this in a minute. This method seems to serve two purposes, retrieve and display information on a specific player and, fill the ArrayList with players data. In my opinion...this is no good. This method should be used for Player Info display to the **JTextArea** and perhaps be called `UI.getPlayerInfo()` and to fill the ArrayList perhaps a method named `UI.loadPlayersInfo()`.

Within the same `UI.createInfo()` method is a major problem. Within the `for` loop, your `if` statement condition is comparing two strings for equality using `==`. This is not going to do what you think. It would help if you used either:

```
// If you want a precise name equality comparison.
if(name.equals(d.getName())) {
```

or

```
// If you want to be more forgiving with letter case.
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(d.getName())) {
```